# Looking for an Ursula K Le Guin Story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ursula-k-le-guin

I am in search of a particular short story by Ursula K. Le Guin that someone told me about. I don't know the title, but it features some sort of tiny black hole type thing that makes time seem to go faster. I heard it likened to people remarking that the year has gone by so fast. Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you sure it's by Le Guin? Looking at a list of her books, none seem to have a black hole.

Comment: I mean, that's what I was told but maybe it isn't?

Comment: I doubt it, but any somebody else can find it.

Comment: That "quote" doesn't make a whole lot of sense since the affected people would not see any difference in their own experience.  Provide more details please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be [*Some Approaches to the Problem of the Shortage of Time.*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58845) It's in her anthology [*The Compass Rose.*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0060914475)

[Incidentally, both of the stories quoted below were written as humorous pieces and never intended to be confused with actual science.]

> THE LITTLE TINY HOLE THEORY
>
> The hypothesis put forward by James Osbold of the Lick Observatory,
> though magnificently comprehensive, presents certain difficulties to
> agencies seeking practical solutions to the problem. Divested of its
> mathematical formulation, Dr. Osbold’s theory may be described in very
> approximate terms as positing the existence of an anomaly in the
> space-time continuum. The cause of the anomaly is a failure of reality
> to meet the specifications of the General Theory of Relativity,
> although only in one minor detail. Its effect on the actual
> constitution of the universe is a local imperfection or flaw, that is,
> a hole in the continuum. The hole, according to Osbold’s calculations,
> is a distinctly spacelike hole. In this spatiality lies its danger,
> since the imbalance thus constituted in the continuum causes a
> compensatory influx from the timelike aspect of the cosmos. In other
> words, time is running out of the hole. This has probably been going
> on ever since the origin of the universe 12 to 15 billion years ago,
> but only lately has the leak grown to noticeable proportions. The
> propounder of the theory is not pessimistic, remarking that it might
> be even worse if the anomaly were in the timelike aspect of the
> continuum, in which case space would be escaping, possibly one
> dimension at a time, which would cause untold discomfort and
> confusion; although, Osbold adds, “In that event we might have time
> enough to do something about it.” Since the theory posits the hole’s
> location somewhere or other, Lick and two Australian observatories
> have arranged a coordinated search for local variations in the red
> shift which might aid in pinpointing the point/instant. “It may still
> be a very small hole,” Osbold says. “Quite tiny. It would not need to
> be very large to do a good deal of damage. But since the effect is so
> noticeable here on Earth, I feel we have a good chance of finding the
> thing perhaps no farther away than the Andromeda Galaxy, and then all
> we’ll need is what you might call a Dutch boy.”

It might also be [*Schrödinger's Cat,*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58840) in the same anthology:

> I suppose birds always tended to be that way, but even the hummingbird
> used to halt for a second in the very center of his metabolic frenzy,
> and hang, still as a hub, present, above the fuchsias—then gone again,
> but you knew something was there besides the blurring brightness. But
> it got so that even robins and pigeons, the heavy impudent birds, were
> a blur; and as for swallows, they cracked the sound barrier. You knew
> of swallows only by the small, curved sonic booms that looped about
> the eaves of old houses in the evening. Worms shot like subway trains
> through the dirt of gardens, among the writhing roots of roses.
> You could scarcely lay a hand on children, by then: too fast to catch,
> too hot to hold. They grew up before your eyes.
>  But then, maybe
> that’s always been true.

Comment: Yes, the Little Tiny Hole Theory is what I was looking for! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Dana: My pleasure. *The Compass Rose* is an often overlooked collection but it's one of my favorite Le Guin anthologies. Well worth seeking out.